# I can't connect to reverse SSH from another server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

New to all this stuff, sorry if it seems basic. I have a Raspberry Pi creating a reverse SSH tunnel (over the Internet) to a router, which reroutes to a RPi that I use as a server.

Tunnel creation : `ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -p 45000 -N -R 2500:localhost:22 user@IP -o "ServerAliveInterval 5" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 2" -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes"`

Server command : `ssh -p 2500 user@localhost`

This works fine, but now I want to do the same with a more "official" server.

So I copied the SSH key to another RPi (to know if it is possible to connect from another device before trying with the server), updated the NAT rules of the router to redirect the tunnel to the second RPi IP, and tried to connect. But it didn't work. (No firewall set up)

To be clear, with this diagram :

```
Remote ===========> router <----------- LocalA
                     but
Remote ===========> router <-----X----- LocalB
```

ssh is installed (which ssh(d) => /usr/bin/ssh(d)), and the service is launched.

Here is the verbose :

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 2500
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2500.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 2500: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2500.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 2500: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2500: Connection refused
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config are the same in both RPi. All the policies from iptables are set to ACCEPT (remote and local). Logs from remote RPi doesn't contain any information from connection attempts. (Seems logic as the ssh connection is not even set ...)

Already tried to set `-L 0.0.0.0:...` but no results neither. (From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/575019/ssh-tunnel-or-reverse-tunnel?rq=1) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/478171/reverse-ssh-tunnel-connexion-refused) ServerFault topics, probably misunderstood the concepts)

Do you have any idea to connect to the tunnel with the second RPi ? Is it even possible without being on the same network ?

Thank you in advance for your responses !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.
I think using twice the same IDs was not a good idea.
Then I set second set of SSH keys for the second 'server', on a second port, and everything went well !